# How do I take an email address entered in a form, and autofill it in another form on a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, autofill

Ok, I have searched this site and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I am completely new to any kind of programming, so be patient please. :)

I have a website, at the bottom will be a "enter your email address to sign up for our newsletters" form. It will only have the one field, and a "submit" button. This submit button will take you to another page and I need the page to have auto-filled in the email address in the email address area, and then the person can choose the rest of their preferences.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this or point me to another post or site or something. Perhaps my search criteria is incorrect. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**  Thank you everyone for your super fast and helpful answers!! I have, with your help, successfully resolved my question. I did some research on what was suggested (like I said, I'm a complete beginner...) and I came across this website, giving detailed instructions! -> [Pre-Fill and Multi-Page Forms with JavaScript](http://www.willmaster.com/library/manage-forms/pre-fill_forms_with_javascript.php)

Comment: You could use session state or pass that variable to another page.  Look up passing parameters or variables on a website on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring information between two pages on a web application is a common problem. Since you've tagged this as Javascript, you might want to consider targeting your second page, let's call it `pagetwo.html`, with the HTTP 'GET' method.

```
<form id="firstPageEmailForm" action="pagetwo.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On submit, the information will be passed to `pagetwo.html` like this: `pagetwo.html?emailaddress=whatever@gmail.com`

You can get at this information using the javascript object `window.location.href`. Just parse out the `emailaddress` field and set the `value` attribute of the input field in the new form on `pagetwo.html`.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the email field in a input element and use the `action` of the `FORM` to point to another page - where you can request : request.form[....

Answer (score 0):

As you only specifically mention javascript, I assume you're trying to do this client side. In which case, you just need to set a cookie, and then retrieve it to populate the field on the subsequent forms.

As you're using jquery, see the [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).